# Command works on ssh, but don't work when using PHP exec() function!

Tags: php, exec

I'm trying to run CutyCapt on my CentOS server, to take websites screenshots!

The problem is that the command `"/downloads/cutycapt/CutyCapt/CutyCapt --url=http://www.google.dk --out=/downloads/cutycapt/CutyCapt/test2.png --min-width=800 --min-height=600"` works when I run it from command line!

But if I try to run it, inside the PHP exec function, nothing happen, and it also returns nothing.

UPDATED:

**The command bellow works on shell.**

```
rm -rf /tmp/.X4-lock&Xvfb :1 -fp /usr/share/X11/fonts/misc -screen 0 1024x768x24 &export DISPLAY=localhost:1.0&CutyCapt --url=http://www.scrapee.net --out=/downloads/cutycapt/CutyCapt/test4.png
```

**but the code bellow donot work on php**
e`xec('rm -rf /tmp/.X4-lock&Xvfb :1 -fp /usr/share/X11/fonts/misc -screen 0 1024x768x24 &export DISPLAY=localhost:1.0&CutyCapt --url=http://www.scrapee.net --out=/downloads/cutycapt/CutyCapt/test4.png',$out);`

Safe mode is off. So I really don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Could someone help-me please? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

CutyCapt needs an X server to work. If you are running it from the CLI as your own user, chances are you already have an X server running for your user. This X server cannot be directly used by the web server user. Start an X server for the web server user and change the DISPLAY environment variable in the beginning of yor PHP script to use this X server.

If this is a server without a screen, consider using Xfvb which is a headless X server.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a permissions problem

`sudo chown www-data:www-data your_file.php`

Comment: When I run whoami in the script I get "nobody". Could this be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

**Using CutyCapt without X server**

You cannot use CutyCapt without an X server, but you can use e.g. Xvfb as light-weight server if you are not running an interactive graphical desktop environment. For example, you could use:

```
  % xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0, 1024x768x24" ./CutyCapt --url=... --out=...
```

http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I'm already using Xvfb. The problem is that it works on command line, but donot work on exec()

Comment: your trying to remove /tmp/.X4-lock, who is the owner for this?